# Get only the next page link from Joomla Pagination UL by PHP

Tags: php, html-lists, joomla2.5

I have the following dynamic output generated by Joomla for page navigation.

```
<ul>
    <li class="pagination-start">
        <span class="pagenav">Start</span>
    </li>
    <li class="pagination-prev">
        <span class="pagenav">Prev</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="pagenav">1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a title="2" href="link-to-page-2" class="pagenav">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="pagination-next">
        <a title="Next" href="link-to-next-page" class="pagenav">Next</a>
    </li>
    <li class="pagination-end">
        <a title="End" href="link-to-last-page" class="pagenav">End</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need only the link data of the next page i.e. **link-to-next-page** which is wrapped by `<li class="pagination-next"></li>`

I need to do it in PHP so that I can make use of the same the same for my Infinite Scrolling plugin.

I can do it through jQuery but it will not serve the purpose. I am looking for a PHP solution to get this.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: You can install your own pagination plugin. Joomla comes with a page navigation plugin that you can adapt to your needs.

Comment: I need to retain the standard pagination system as it is also used by other components. Just want take out the required link from the output may be by preg_match. I don't have much knowledge in PHP so seeking help. I want to extract the href data where the title="Next".

Comment: Add a condition in the pagination plugin to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your jquery code:

```
navSelector  : '.pagenav',    // selector for the paged navigation
nextSelector : '.pagenav a[title="Next"]',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
```

I have not debugged the above code, simply adapted it from Joomla 1.5 (see [here](http://forum.techbubble.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2486))